# Is there a common set of operators that cannot be overloaded in all languages of OOPS?

Tags: polymorphism, operator-overloading

I know that set of operators that cannot be overloaded change from one programming language to another in OOPS. But i want to know whether there any set of operators that can't be overloaded by any OOPS languages?

Comment: Operators like `+, && -gt` or keywords like `if, else, int`

Comment: `+` and `&&` are overloadable in C++.

Comment: Since it is always possible that there exists some OOP language where everything is overloadable, this question is either too trivial to answer, or impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking about commonalities in _all_ programming languages, of which there are none.